# Getting Connection refused error when running drupal with docker

Tags: drupal

I am getting Connection refused error when trying to install drupal on my local with docker desktop. Here is the docker-compose.yml -

```
version: "3"

services:
    mysql:
        image: mysql:latest
        container_name: mysql
        restart: unless-stopped
        env_file: .env
        ports:
            - 3306:3306
            - 33060:33060
        volumes:
            - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql

    drupal:
        image: drupal:php8.2-fpm
        container_name: drupal
        depends_on:
            - mysql
        restart: unless-stopped
        volumes:
            - ./web:/var/www/html
            - ./vendor:/opt/drupal/vendor
            - ./composer.json:/opt/drupal/composer.json
            - ./composer.lock:/opt/drupal/composer.lock
        links:
            - mysql

    webserver:
        image: nginx:stable-alpine
        container_name: webserver
        depends_on:
            - drupal
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - 80:80
            - 443:443
        volumes:
            - ./web:/var/www/html
            - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
            - ./nginx/certs:/etc/nginx/certs/self-signed
```

Here is drupal settings.local.php -

```
$databases['default']['default'] = [
    'database' => 'gcpc',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'root',
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'port' => '3306',
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'prefix' => '',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
];

$config['system.logging']['error_level']='verbose';
```

The mysql container is also running at port 3306.

This is my first time working on drupal with docker. I am not actually sure what is going wrong. i have followed the drupal documentation but couldn't figure out the issue. It might be a minor issue but I cannot figure it out. Could someone please help wm with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

database "host" in your settings should be the name of your container "mysql", not 127.0.0.1